# Problems with rendering view when using DataTable in Laravel 5.2

Tags: json, laravel, datatable, render

I am currently using datatables in Laravel 5.2, it seems like I can successfully pass the JSON data but failed to render view. I really dunno what is wrong here.

Here is my Datatable Controller code:

```
public function getIndex()
    {
        return view('event.report');
    }

    /**
     * Process datatables ajax request.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function anyData(Request $request)
    {
        //$developers = Event::lists('developer','developer');
        $events = Event::select(['name','startDate','endDate','venue','developer','client','agency','allowance']);
        return \Datatables::of($events)
            ->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
                if ($request->input('developer')) {
                    $query->where('developer', '=', "{$request->get('developer')}");
                }
            })
            ->make(true);
    }
```

Here is my view in event.report:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <title>Attender Monthly Report Page</title>

    <div class="container">
        {{ Form::open(['url' => '/getreport','id'=>'search']) }}
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Select Developer Name:') }}
        {{ Form::select('developer', ['abc'=>'abc','def'=>'def','123'=>'123'],null,['id' => 'name']) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}

        <div class="search">
        <a  href="{{ url('/excel') }}" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Export as Excel</a>
        <table class="table table-hover" id="result">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Event Name</th>
                <th>Start_Date</th>
                <th>End_Date</th>
                <th>Venue</th>
                <th>Attender</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Agency</th>
                <th>Allowance</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
            </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@push('scripts')
<script>
    var oTable =
            $('#result').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: '{{ url('/getreport') }}',
                    data: function (d) {
                        d.name = $('select[name=name]').val();
                    }
                },

                columns: [
                    { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                    { data: 'startDate', name: 'startDate' },
                    { data: 'endDate', name: 'endDate' },
                    { data: 'venue', name: 'venue' },
                    { data: 'developer', name: 'developer' },
                    { data: 'client', name: 'client' },
                    { data: 'agency', name: 'agency' },
                    { data: 'allowance', name: 'allowance' }
                ]
            });

    $('#search').on('submit', function(e) {
        oTable.draw();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
@endpush
```

And here is my route:

```
Route::post('/getreport','DatatablesController@anyData');
Route::get('/viewreport','DatatablesController@getIndex');
```

This is my JSON data posted to /getreport page:

```
{
"draw": 0,
"recordsTotal": 4,
"recordsFiltered": 2,
"data": [
{
"name": "sfdwseef",
"startDate": "2016-02-03",
"endDate": "2016-02-23",
"venue": "dgegw",
"developer": "123",
"client": "dgsfdse",
"agency": "dgfsdg",
"allowance": "567"
},
{
"name": "dfgdrer3terr",
"startDate": "2016-03-07",
"endDate": "2016-03-08",
"venue": "fhghfghf",
"developer": "123",
"client": "fhgfhty",
"agency": "hrthyj",
"allowance": "43"
}
],
"queries": [
{
"query": "select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `events`) count_row_table",
"bindings": [],
"time": 1
},
{
"query": "select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `events` where `developer` = ?) count_row_table",
"bindings": [
"123"
],
"time": 0
},
{
"query": "select `name`, `startDate`, `endDate`, `venue`, `developer`, `client`, `agency`, `allowance` from `events` where `developer` = ?",
"bindings": [
"123"
],
"time": 0
}
],
"input": {
"_token": "oGq4pYPTXdGWf7LJf8YUb5nOX6gqbZWp1n5iZizg",
"developer": "123"
}
}
```

And one more thing,if I want my dropdown to display options from developer column in Event Model,how shud I change my code?

Comment: If you're having trouble on the view side of things with datatables try opening the web page in chrome with chrome dev tools open and look out for any errors. Do you see anything?

Comment: @haakym,nothing in errors.

Comment: It does not displaying /viewreport page,instead it stop after navigate to /getreport page.

Comment: `viewreport` is your view with the datatable in it right, so you're telling me you can't even see that? I thought you meant there's no data in the table, not that you couldn't see any of the page. What do you mean by navigate to `getreport`, there should be no navigation to that page only an ajax request that happens in the background.

Comment: @haakym,it means when i submit in /viewreport view,it display /getreport in the url with these json data in background when inspect using chrome.It means tat the ajax request is successful but y it not display the /viewreport view with datatable?

Comment: So the issue is with the form submission, not the initial rendering of the datatable?

Comment: @haakym,I think so.I am still new in laravel.

Comment: What I am asking you is two questions: When you load up `viewreport` do you see data in the datatable? Yes or no? And is your error with the form submission? Yes or no? Thanks.

Comment: @haakym,no see data when load /viewreport. Form submission oso no see data.

Comment: @joshua I'm having same issue, how did you resolve your issue ?